# Not getting empty string when no input is provided

Tags: python

**About the Problem:**

The function was required to return names in the format
`Name: first_name, last_name`, and return nothing when no input is provided.
For example;" " would return an empty string

**Issue:**

The function should return an empty string wen no input is provided but giving `Name:`  as an output

**Code**

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    return "Name: "+ first_name + " " + last_name
print(format_name("", ""))
#Should return an empty string
```

Comment: Check your learning material about tests again. SO is not a good replacement for a course or a tutorial.

Comment: Okay, well, why do you think the code does that? Can you think of a way to fix the problem? What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if that was what you meant but hope this will solve your problem

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
   if(first_name == "" and last_name ==""):
      return ""
   return "Name: "+ first_name + " " + last_name
print(format_name("", ""))
#Should return an empty string

print(format_name("Xyz", "abc"))
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you. A slight change to a @codingIsLife answers

**Code :**

```
def getname(first_name,last_name):
  if not first_name and not last_name:
    return "Name:"
  else:
    return "Name: "+ first_name + " " + last_name  
print(getname("",""))
```

**Output :**

```
Name :
```